# Mac m1: rescue in block in activate_dependencies when pod repo update

Tags: ios, ruby, cocoapods, homebrew

The info:

```
192:~$ pod repo update
/Library/Ruby/Site/2.6.0/rubygems/specification.rb:1453:in `rescue in block in activate_dependencies': Could not find 'json' (>= 1.5.1) among 47 total gem(s) (Gem::MissingSpecError)
Checked in 'GEM_PATH=/Users/caiqiang/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.0:/Users/caiqiang/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0:/usr/local/Cellar/cocoapods/1.11.3/libexec' at: /usr/local/Cellar/cocoapods/1.11.3/libexec/specifications/algoliasearch-1.27.5.gemspec, execute `gem env` for more information
    from /Library/Ruby/Site/2.6.0/rubygems/specification.rb:1450:in `block in activate_dependencies'
    from /Library/Ruby/Site/2.6.0/rubygems/specification.rb:1439:in `each'
    from /Library/Ruby/Site/2.6.0/rubygems/specification.rb:1439:in `activate_dependencies'
    from /Library/Ruby/Site/2.6.0/rubygems/specification.rb:1421:in `activate'
    from /Library/Ruby/Site/2.6.0/rubygems/specification.rb:1457:in `block in activate_dependencies'
    from /Library/Ruby/Site/2.6.0/rubygems/specification.rb:1439:in `each'
    from /Library/Ruby/Site/2.6.0/rubygems/specification.rb:1439:in `activate_dependencies'
    from /Library/Ruby/Site/2.6.0/rubygems/specification.rb:1421:in `activate'
    from /Library/Ruby/Site/2.6.0/rubygems/specification.rb:1457:in `block in activate_dependencies'
    from /Library/Ruby/Site/2.6.0/rubygems/specification.rb:1439:in `each'
    from /Library/Ruby/Site/2.6.0/rubygems/specification.rb:1439:in `activate_dependencies'
    from /Library/Ruby/Site/2.6.0/rubygems/specification.rb:1421:in `activate'
    from /Library/Ruby/Site/2.6.0/rubygems.rb:286:in `block in activate_bin_path'
    from /Library/Ruby/Site/2.6.0/rubygems.rb:285:in `synchronize'
    from /Library/Ruby/Site/2.6.0/rubygems.rb:285:in `activate_bin_path'
    from /usr/local/Cellar/cocoapods/1.11.3/libexec/bin/pod:23:in `<main>'
/Library/Ruby/Site/2.6.0/rubygems/dependency.rb:311:in `to_specs': Could not find 'json' (>= 1.5.1) among 47 total gem(s) (Gem::MissingSpecError)
Checked in 'GEM_PATH=/Users/caiqiang/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.0:/Users/caiqiang/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0:/usr/local/Cellar/cocoapods/1.11.3/libexec' , execute `gem env` for more information
    from /Library/Ruby/Site/2.6.0/rubygems/specification.rb:1451:in `block in activate_dependencies'
    from /Library/Ruby/Site/2.6.0/rubygems/specification.rb:1439:in `each'
    from /Library/Ruby/Site/2.6.0/rubygems/specification.rb:1439:in `activate_dependencies'
    from /Library/Ruby/Site/2.6.0/rubygems/specification.rb:1421:in `activate'
    from /Library/Ruby/Site/2.6.0/rubygems/specification.rb:1457:in `block in activate_dependencies'
    from /Library/Ruby/Site/2.6.0/rubygems/specification.rb:1439:in `each'
    from /Library/Ruby/Site/2.6.0/rubygems/specification.rb:1439:in `activate_dependencies'
    from /Library/Ruby/Site/2.6.0/rubygems/specification.rb:1421:in `activate'
    from /Library/Ruby/Site/2.6.0/rubygems/specification.rb:1457:in `block in activate_dependencies'
    from /Library/Ruby/Site/2.6.0/rubygems/specification.rb:1439:in `each'
    from /Library/Ruby/Site/2.6.0/rubygems/specification.rb:1439:in `activate_dependencies'
    from /Library/Ruby/Site/2.6.0/rubygems/specification.rb:1421:in `activate'
    from /Library/Ruby/Site/2.6.0/rubygems.rb:286:in `block in activate_bin_path'
    from /Library/Ruby/Site/2.6.0/rubygems.rb:285:in `synchronize'
    from /Library/Ruby/Site/2.6.0/rubygems.rb:285:in `activate_bin_path'
    from /usr/local/Cellar/cocoapods/1.11.3/libexec/bin/pod:23:in `<main>'
```

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved after I uninstalled rvm.